# Installation conflicts with httpd on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, aws, php7

When installing 'yum install -y php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd' on an Amazon Linux AMI server, I'm receiving these conflicts:

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
```

I'm uncertain how to resolve. The conflicts appear to be with the httpd installation and what I am attempting to install.

It looks like the Amazon Linux AMI has httpd installed by default

```
yum list installed | grep httpd
httpd.x86_64                         2.2.34-1.16.amzn1             @amzn-main   
httpd-tools.x86_64                   2.2.34-1.16.amzn1             @amzn-main
```

Full output of attempted install below:

```
sudo yum install -y php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql56-server.x86_64 0:5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql56-errmsg(x86-64) = 5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql56-common(x86-64) = 5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL(mysql56) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Data::Dumper) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql56(x86-64) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql56(alternatives) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql56(alternatives) for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-config for package: mysql56-server-5.6.41-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php70.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70-cli(x86-64) = 7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 for package: php70-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70-common(x86-64) = 7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 for package: php70-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x86-64 for package: php70-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70-common for package: php70-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24 for package: php70-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php70-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70-pdo(x86-64) = 7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 for package: php70-mysqlnd-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24.x86_64 0:2.4.34-1.82.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24-tools = 2.4.34-1.82.amzn1 for package: httpd24-2.4.34-1.82.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package mysql-config.x86_64 0:5.5.61-1.22.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package mysql56.x86_64 0:5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package mysql56-common.x86_64 0:5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package mysql56-errmsg.x86_64 0:5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL56.x86_64 0:4.023-5.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.1018(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL56-4.023-5.21.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.1018()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL56-4.023-5.21.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.627-4.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlServer) >= 0.2001 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlClient) >= 0.2000 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.8.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package perl-Data-Dumper.x86_64 0:2.145-3.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php70-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php70-common.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70-process(x86-64) = 7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 for package: php70-common-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70-xml(x86-64) = 7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 for package: php70-common-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70-json(x86-64) for package: php70-common-7.0.32-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package php70-pdo.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd24-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.34-1.82.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package mysql56-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.41-1.30.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package perl-PlRPC.noarch 0:0.2020-14.7.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon) >= 0.13 for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Test) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Log) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Zlib) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
---> Package php70-json.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php70-process.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php70-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.31.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.061-2.12.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.12.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.12.amzn1.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-Daemon.noarch 0:0.48-5.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.061-3.11.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.061-4.1.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.34-1.82.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.34
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.34-1.82.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.34
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I presume httpd24 is coming in as a dependency of ... php or mysql?? Can you show more of the input & output?

Comment: It looks like the Amazon Linux AMI has httpd installed by default

And the dependency for httpd in attempted install likely comes from the mysql packages. Full output of attempted installation added to initial question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Not sure if this output gives any ideas of what could be causing the conflict. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry; I'm just boggled that a scripting language requires an HTTP server!

Answer (score 3):

try with :

yum install mod24_ssl.x86_64

with AMI linux

Answer (score 1):

First thing to find out, is why httpd & httpd-tools are installed.If they don't need to be installed, you can remove them and then replace them with the httpd24 versions (which would be preferable, 2.2 is pretty old). To find out what, if anything, requires httpd & httpd-tools on your system, run:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires httpd
rpm -q --whatrequires httpd-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an almost identical issue on a centos6, using @amzn-updates repo, with httpd 2.4, not 2.2. 
To resolve this, i removed httpd-tools .

`yum remove httpd24-tools`

It looked like it removed also httpd.  No biggie.

Then i installed php, which is where i was getting the conflict

`yum install php72-..`

Then i installed php back, then i installed httpd back.

`yum install httpd24`

That resolved it for me.